# Critique my JAXB object wrapper

Tags: data-binding, jaxb, word-wrap

I have a question on wrapping a jaxb created class and would really like to hear your inputs.

My xsd looks a bit like:

```
<ComplexService>
    <ComplexObject1>
        <Element1></Element1>
       <Parameter></Parameter>
    </ComplexObject1>

   <ComplexObject2>
        <Element2> </Element2>
        <Parameter> </Parameter>
   </ComplexObject2>

   ...

  <ComplexObject10>
        <Element10> </Element10>
        <Parameter> </Parameter>
  </ComplexObjec10>
```

The class created after running the above xsd through xjc looks a bit like :

```
public class ComplexService{

ComplexObject1 object1;
ComplexObject2 object2;
...
ComplexObject10 object10;

public static class ComplexObject1{
//Accessors and mutators on ComplexObject1
}

public static class ComplexObject2{
//Accessors and mutators on ComplexObject1
}

...

public static class ComplexObject10{
//Accessors and mutators on ComplexObject1
}

}
```

Now I want to create a wrapper around these CompleObjects as well the ComplexService class.

```
public class WrappedComplexObject1{

private final ComplexObject1;

public WrappedComplexObject1(){
complexObject1 = new ComplexObject1();
}

//Delegate calls to the underlying ComplexObject1
public String getServiceName(){
return complexObject1.getServiceName();
}

}
```

My questions are these:

1. Would the above way be the preferred way to wrap the class? My objectives are to not mess with the underlying classes created by xjc; to provide a better named api (Class as well as method names).
2. I also want to validate the data in these objects. Therefore I am thinking of using the 
   decorator pattern to further wrap WrappedComplexObject1. Would this be a recommended approach?
3. Lastly, the xsd contains the element "Parameter" which is structurally the same (just contains one value field). However, when xjc created the ComplexService class, for every ComplexObject a new Parameter class was created.

Should I worry about just having one wrapper class for "Parameter" or should I simply create one Parameter wrapper classes per ComplexObject.

Any suggestions, ideas, code samples would be most helpful.

Thanks

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Well as you can see there were no responses, so I am unsure if my way is the "preferred" way. However, this is what I ended up doing:

//Defined a Wrapper Super class. All the classes I wrapped would descend from this.

```
public abstract class WrappedSuperComplexObject{

    protected boolean isValid;
    protected String name;

    public boolean isValid(){
        return isValid;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;    
    }

}
```

//Wrapper product class

```
 public class WrappedComplexBondObject extends WrappedSuperComplexObject{ 

    //ComplexObject is an internal object created by JAXB 
    private final JAXBElement<Product> productElement; 

    public WrappedComplexBondObject(JAXBElement<Product> productElement) { 
           this.isValid = true;
           this.name = ProductEnum.BOND;
           this.productElement= productElement; 
    } 

    //Delegate all get/set class to the internal object
    public String getElement1() { 
           return productElement.getElement1(); 
    } 

    public String getParameter1() { 
           return productElement.getParameter1(); 
    } 

    }
```

// And then have a factory class that validates and creates the specific product instance.

```
public WrappedSuperComplexObject createWrappedInstance(JAXBElement<DataDocument> jaxbElement) throws WrappedException{

    DataDocument document = jaxbElement.getValue();
    WrappedValidationResult result = WrappedValidator.validate(document);

    if ( !result.isValid() ){
        throw new WrappedException(result.getMessage());
    }

    JAXBElement<Product> productElem = (JAXBElement<Product>) trade.getProduct();   
    String productName = productElem.getName().getLocalPart().toUpperCase();

    WrappedSuperComplexObject product = null;

     switch( WrappedProductEnum.valueOf(productName) ){

        case BOND:
            product = new WrappedComplexBondObject(productElem);
        break;

        default:
            product = new UnsupportedProduct("Product is not Supported.");
        break;

    }

    return product;     
}
```

For question 3, I ended up extracting the "Parameter" element from my main xsd and created a new xsd just for Parameter. I then referenced the "Parameter" element from my main xjc.

Hope this helps.